# How to navigate through html tab with casperjs

Tags: html, css-selectors, casperjs

i need your experience in casperjs!
I am trying to access a web page (which is not an issue) and to navigate through a html tab.
When i access the page it is by default always showing the first tab "General" but i need to switch to "Options" tab so that i can access one field that i am interested to modify the value!

Sorry, can't post images yet!

Html code:

```
<b>&nbsp;<b>
    <table class="commonfont" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="/tab_between.png" border="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><input name="" src="/tab_sel_left.png" border="0" type="image"></td>      
              <td align="center" background="/tab_sel_bg.png">
              &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].tabIndex.value='1'-1;document.forms[0].methodCalled.value='gotoTabChange';doSubmit();" tabindex="4" class="menu1itemSel">General</a>
                &nbsp;
                </td>
              <td><input name="" src="/tab_sel_right.png" border="0" type="image"></td>
              <td width="1"></td>   
              <td><input name="" src="/tab_unsel_left.png" border="0" type="image"></td>
              <td align="center" background="/tab_unsel_bg.png">
              &nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:document.forms[0].tabIndex.value='2'-1;document.forms[0].methodCalled.value='gotoTabChange';doSubmit();" tabindex="4" class="menu1itemUnSel">Options</a>
                &nbsp;</td>
              <td><input name="" src="/tab_unsel_right.png" border="0" type="image"></td>
              <td width="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
</b></b>
```

My casper.js file looks like this:

```
...
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("DB", "Login into DB 2");
        this.click('a#changeThis1_link');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Options", "DB Options");
        this.click('a#menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Change", "DB -Change -Step 1/2");
        this.fill('form[name="dbActionForm"]', {
          'generalParams.poolSize': '1',
        }, false);
        this.click('input[name="Apply"]');
    });
...
```

I just can't figure out what should this line look like:

this.click('a#menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');

since this isn't working!!!

Execution printout:

```
modifying DB pool size:
Test file: /target.js
# DB modify
PASS DB has the correct title
PASS login form is found
PASS Login into DB
PASS Login into DB 1
PASS Login into DB 2
PASS DB Options
FAIL Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: a#menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: a#menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]
#           CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: a#menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]
#               at mouseEvent (/casper.js:1323)
#               at click (/casper.js:428)
#               at /target.js:34
#               at runStep (/casper.js:1523)
#               at checkStep (/casper.js:368)
#    stack: not provided
```

Any clue what i am doing wrong and how can i overcome this issue?

Thanks for your time

Some updates and more information:

After Fanch information, I changed the casperjs to:

...
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("DB", "Login into DB 2");
        this.click('a#changeThis1_link');
    });

```
casper.then(function() {
    test.assertTextExists("Options", "DB Options");
    this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
});

casper.then(function() {
    test.assertTextExists("Change", "DB -Change -Step 1/2");
    this.fill('form[name="dbActionForm"]', {
      'generalParams.poolSize': '1',
    }, false);
    this.click('input[name="Apply"]');
});
```

...

This a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"] solved my error about changing the tab but i still have the issue with reading/changing the field generalParams.poolSize.

I even added then waitForSelector/waitForText but still get the error: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found

See casperjs:

```
...
    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Options", "DB Options");
        this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
    });

    casper.waitForSelector("a#dve_menu_datarepositories", function() {
         this.echo("1.Loading form");
    });

    casper.waitForText("50", function() {   //the field that i want to change has text '50'
         this.echo("2.Loading form");
    });

    casper.then(function() {
        test.assertTextExists("Change", "DB -Change -Step 1/2");
        this.fill('form[name="dbActionForm"]', {
          'generalParams.poolSize': '1',
        }, false);
        this.click('input[name="Apply"]');
    });
...
```

Thanks again

Sorry i was away for a while, here is some html part of the page:

```
<a name="topofpage">
    <form autocomplete="off" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/db.do" method="post" name="dbActionForm">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr height="100%">
                                    <td valign="top" height="100%"></td>
                                    <td valign="top" height="100%" background="/menu3_sel_right1.png"></td>
                                    <td class="commonfont" width="100%" valign="top" background="/menu3_sel_right1.png" align="left">
                                        <b>
                                            <b>
                                                <table class="commonfont" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" onkeypress="return onWizardPageKeyPress(event);">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr id="generalParams.poolSize_TR" class="formpagefieldname" style="display:table-row;">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <a id="generalParams.poolSize_changeA" style="visibility:hidden;" title="Undo Change" onclick="revertSingleChange('generalParams.poolSize', false); dependantsRunOnLoad(document.body); return false;" href="javascript:;"></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" onblur="if (!this.disabled) {onChangeProperty(this, false);} " onpropertychanged="if (!this.disabled) {onChangeProperty(this, false);} " onkeyup="if (!this.disabled) { onChangeProperty(this, false); }" tabindex="2" title="10" size="30" value="50" name="generalParams.poolSize"></input>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </b>
                                        </b>
```

I still have the problem filling in the form!

```
FAIL Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: Errors encountered while filling form: form not found
```

Any clue more?

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: That is what dev tools are for. Type `$$('a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]')` in the console of your developer tools in the browser (firefox or chrome). You can even check XPaths with `$x('//a[@tabindex="4"]')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
this.click('a.menu1itemUnSel[tabindex="4"]');
```

-> <kbd>#</kbd> = div, <kbd>.</kbd> = class

Comment: Thanks again! This seem to solve this problem but now suddenly when i try to change a field in the form it says that *`Errors encountered while filling form: form not found`* in casperjs! But when i don't change tab i can change fields of the same form, which should be dbActionForm!!!

Comment: Show us the HTML for your filling form problem :) You might have a problem because when you change tab you don't use a `wait` statement, as `waitForSelector`, `waitForText` before filling the new form.